# Trouble installing Mongoid with Rails 3 on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, mongoid

In my Gemfile:

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.3"
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.4"
```

When I run `bundle install` I get the error below:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    mongoid (~> 2.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activemodel (~> 3.1) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 3.0.6) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activemodel (3.0.6)
```

I've tried pointing to github for the version, as is suggested in some other posts, but when I do this and run `bundle install`, I get another error:

```
Fetching http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:579:in
``': No such file or directory - git clone "http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.gi
t" "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/mongoid-96bbbaf83f2d1e3487e
c2c95b9e5148015a7a346" --bare --no-hardlinks (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:579:in `git'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:653:in `cache'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:551:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:356:in `block in converge_locked_specs'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:345:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:345:in `converge_locked_specs'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:143:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:90:in `specs'
```

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, bson_ext needs to be built natively. This means that somehow you must build it on Windows. The errors are pointing to x86-mingw32, which can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)

The reason you would need that is because there are a couple of libraries that are platform dependent. Hope this sets you in the right direction.

Comment: The gems actually seem to install just fine by themselves but if I run `rails g mongoid:config` or `bundle install`, both of these commands produce the error above. Given this bit of information, would you still assume that there was a problem with the building/installing of the gems, or would you think that installing `x86-mingw32` would do the trick? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'll still go with installing x86-mingw32. Have you installed MongoDB btw? Not the gem, but the actual database.

Comment: Will do, but it looks like the page you linked is currently broken. I'll look for it elsewhere, but you might want to update your response, should I happen to accept your answer :)

Comment: I tried installing x86-mingw32, and I added the path to its `bin` folder in my `Path` environment variable, but I still get the same error. Are you sure the error points to x86-mingw32? The error looks to me like it's an ActiveModel problem, but `gem list` shows `activemodel (3.1.3, 3.0.6)`