# Get mongoDB working with Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am about to learn more about Rails "way" of developing web applications (i have asp.net background). I want to create a simple application with Rails as mainframe, MongoDB as db and angularJS as front-end. But right now i am having huge problems to get rails working with MongoDB. I added folowing into my gemfile :

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
```

but when i run `bundle update` og `bundle install` i am getting folowing error:

```
>     Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> 
>     C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb creating Makefile
> 
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
> 
> make "DESTDIR=" generating native-i386-mingw32.def compiling native.c
> In file included from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:0,
>                  from native.c:26: c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:125:14: error: size of array
> 'ruby_che ck_sizeof_voidp' is negative In file included from
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:0,
>                  from native.c:26: c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function
> 'rb_float_value': c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:826:13:
> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
> [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In
> function 'rb_num2char_inline':
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1214:35: warning: cast to
> pointer from  integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1214:35: warning: cast to
> pointer from  integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1214:35: warning: cast to
> pointer from  integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1215:9: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1215:9: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1215:9: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1515:12: warning: cast to
> pointer from  integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
> c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1532:12: warning: cast to
> pointer from  integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> native.c: In function 'rb_float_from_bson_double': native.c:213:11:
> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast] native.c:213:11: warning: cast to pointer from
> integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:213:11:
> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast] native.c:214:21: warning: cast to pointer from
> integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:214:21:
> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast] native.c:214:21: warning: cast to pointer from
> integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c: In
> function 'rb_integer_from_bson_int32': native.c:358:39: warning: cast
> to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c:358:39: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:358:39: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c: In function 'rb_bson_to_int64_t': native.c:381:18: warning:
> cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast] native.c:381:18: warning: cast to pointer from
> integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:381:18:
> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast] native.c: In function 'rb_string_set_int32':
> native.c:529:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:529:34: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c:529:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:532:10: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c:532:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:532:10: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c: In function 'rb_string_check_for_illegal_characters':
> native.c:548:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:548:14: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c:548:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:548:45: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast]
> native.c:548:45: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
> size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] native.c:548:45: warning: cast to
> pointer from integer of different size [-Wint- to-pointer-cast] make:
> *** [native.o] Error 1
> 
> make failed, exit code 2
> 
> Gem files will remain installed in
> C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bson-2.3. 0 for inspection.
> Results logged to
> C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.0.0/bs
> on-2.3.0/gem_make.out An error occurred while installing bson (2.3.0),
> and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install bson -v
> '2.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

As i can see there are multiple problems with maeking mongoDB to work with Rails 4, does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong? Or maybe i should switch to some other noSQL db?

Comment: Have a look at this to help you install `mongoid` on Windows.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595558/trouble-installing-mongoid-with-rails-3-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Mongid at [Ready For Rails 4](http://www.ready4rails4.net/), and got this:

> Version 4 will support Rails 4 but it hasn't been released yet

There is only  `4.0.0.rc2,4.0.0.rc1,4.0.0.beta,4.0.0.alpha`

Comment: You can try forcing `4.0.0.rc2` in gemfile.